# When writing tests with selenium how can you view the resulting HTML?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-ide

Take for example the following selenium test in python:

```
 import unittest
 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

 class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):

     def setUp(self):
         self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

     def test_search_in_python_org(self):
         driver = self.driver
         driver.get("http://www.python.org")
         self.assertIn("Python", driver.title)
         elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
         elem.send_keys("selenium")
         elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
         self.assertIn("Google", driver.title)

     def tearDown(self):
         self.driver.close()

 if __name__ == "__main__":
     unittest.main()
```

Taken from: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html#id2

The resulting output is something like:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 15.566s

OK
```

Is there any way to get selenium to output the html after it has executed its browser actions?

Basically, I am using Selenium IDE for Firefox to record actions on the browser. I want to play them back on python, get the resulting html, and based on that html take further action (e.g. the 1st selenium test might be to log on to a website and navigate somewhere. Based on what is there I want to conduct a second test (w. the user still logged on)). Is this possible using selenium?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: In selenoimRC there's a `gethtml()` method, you could try looking for something similar and using python's IO to write it out to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though your tests might end up being dependant on each other, which is a **very very bad** idea.

Nonetheless, the `page_source` function will return the full HTML of the current page the driver is looking at:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py#429